# How do I change the NSPrintInfo duplex?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

Using `UIKit` I can set up a print job using `UIPrintInfo` as normal and set the `printInfo.duplex` to `UIPrintInfoDuplexShortEdge` which means that when I print multiple pages in landscape orientation the document comes out nicely laid out on the paper.

I would like to do the same in `Cocoa` but I can't find the equivalent. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the low-level [Core Printing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/index.html) object and modify that:

```
PMPrintSettings printSettings = printInfo.PMPrintSettings;
if (PMSetDuplex(printSettings, kPMDuplexTumble) == noErr)
    [printInfo updateFromPMPrintSettings];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Core Printing API has been broken for many years, in my experience.  The value of the duplex setting is completely ignored by the print dialog, at least when passed to -[printWithInfo:autoRotate:] from a PDFView subclass.  It works when linked against the 10.5 SDK, but fails when linked against the 10.8 SDK or later (up to and including the current SDK).  Filed FB9994116.